joint measurability and adaptedness of Ito processes
I would like to understand the properties of Ito processes
$$
X(t)=X(0)+\int_0^tu(s)ds+\int_0^tv(s)dW(s)
$$
for $u\in\mathcal{L}_{ad}(\Omega,L^1[0,t])$ (the space of functions that are jointly measurable, $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted and a.s. $L^1$-integrable with respect to time), $v\in\mathcal{L}_{ad}(\Omega,L^2[0,t])$ (the space of functions that are jointly measurable, $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted and a.s. $L^2$-integrable with respect to time), and $X(0)$ being $\mathcal{F}(0)$-measurable. I understand that the stochastic integral is $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted, has (under the assumption of a complete filtration) a continuous version (with which it is identified), and is jointly measurable, and would like to understand whether the same properties hold for $X$, i.e. would like to prove that
$$Y(t)=\int_0^t u(s) ds$$
is jointly measurable and $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted.
My considerations so far:

$Y$ being $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted:

Due to $u$ being jointly measurable and adapted, it has a jointly measurable and progressively measurable modification $\tilde{u}$. As $\tilde{u}: [0,t]\times\Omega$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times\mathcal{F}(t)$-measurable and $\tilde{u}$ is a.s. integrable with respect to time due to being a modification of $u$, Fubini's theorem implies that $\int_0^t\tilde{u}(s) ds$ is $\mathcal{F}(t)$-measurable. The adaptedness of $Y$ follows then from $\mathcal{F}(t)$ being complete and $u$ being a modification of $\tilde{u}$ (and the probability space being complete).
Is this reasoning correct? And does there possibly exist a more elementary proof, avoiding the (difficult to prove) result that every jointly measurable and adapted process has a progressively measurable modification?

joint measurability of $Y$:

If $Y$ would be continuous as function of $t$, we could conclude that $Y$ (as continuous and $\mathcal{F}(t)$-adapted process) is jointly measurable. However, we only know that $Y$ (as Lebesgue integral of a.s. integrable paths) is a.s. continuous, so I am not sure how to conclude?

In 1., you should prove that $Y_t = \int^t_0 \widetilde u(s)ds$ a.s. for all $t \geq 0$ from the fact that $\widetilde u$ is a modification of $u$, then use $\mathcal F_t$ is complete.

There's a result somewhere that asserts if $u$ is (jointly) measurable and adapted, the filtration satisfies the usual hypothesis, plus
$$ \forall (\omega,t), \quad \int_0^t u(\omega, s) ds < \infty, \qquad (*)$$
then there is a progressive process $\widetilde{u}$ such that
$$  \lambda \times P\big(\widetilde u \neq u \big) = 0.$$
By Fubini, we could have
$$  \forall t \geq 0, \quad \int_0^t u(\omega, s) ds = \int_0^t \widetilde u(\omega, s) ds \quad P-a.s.$$
Consequently, if $u$ satisfies above assumption w.r.t $(t,\omega)$, then $Y_t \in \mathcal F_t$ because it is a.s. equal to $\int_0^t \widetilde u(s)ds$ (and $Y_t(\omega)$ is defined for every $\omega$), which is well-known to be in $\mathcal F_t$, plus the filtration is complete. So in 1., you have to answer yourself how $Y_t(\omega)$ is defined for each $\omega$ (Hint: take a representative $u$ that satisfies $(*)$) .
In 2., when you have $Y_t$ is defined $\omega$-wise, it is then continuous, thus progressive.
